# Move PostgreSQL databases to new Ubuntu machine

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu

Unfortunately an Ubuntu machine I manage has stopped working, and after much work it seems like I'll have to reinstall the system. All the data from the old system is intact and backed up.

Among this data is a PostgreSQL installation with some databases (that was running isolated on this machine.) My goal is to move this data as is, and run it on the fresh install.

Since the old system is not running, I can't do a `pg_dump`.

According to [this article](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/backup-file.html) it should be possible to mode the data folder, but there are two restrictions mentioned. What I do not fully understand is if this will be a problem for me?

I cant seem to find much information on this online, since all refer to the preferred `pg_dump`-method.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If postgres was shutdown prior the machine stopped working, probably. Else - it might or might not work - no one can tell as no one can reproduce your specific problem. Therefore your question borders on being off-topic

Comment: As long as you use same version of postgres (+ same architecture and OS) - you should be able to copy data directory without any issues.

Comment: @knitti Postgres does not need a clean shutdown to start DB from data directory. It has WAL files to recover from any possible loss from unclen shutdown.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko 1. wal_level is minimal by default and  2. how you going to use WAL without base backup?..

Comment: @petersv those two limitations can be your case and not. first - atomic snapshot - yes you have it if your server died - there's a huge chance that what left in IO buffers left for all objects, same for clog. this way you can just try copying whole directories set (data ,clog, tablespaces, whatever) to a new machine and use exact postgres.conf... If you are lucky, server will roll on WAL (if you kept those) and will open db, if not - not...

Comment: @VaoTsun WAL primary purpose is to allow DB restore on unclean shutdown (like power loss). `wal_level` is minimal by default because it is enough for restore from shutdown. Other levels are used for PiTR and continuous backups but are not needed for recovery.

Comment: @VaoTsun For a postgres server with `fsync` on it is not possible to "lose" data in IO buffers on server failure. Every committed transaction is in WAL and will be restored on postgres cluster start.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko yes, and fsync is by default on - true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestions in the comments to the initial answer, the Postgres directories where copied to a new host and the database started without any problems.